# symfony persist doesn't save all attributes

Tags: serialization, symfony, persist

In my symfony 3 project i got a entity to log changes.
To save the changes I'm using two serialized arrays with the old and the new objects.

Log-Class:

```
/*
 * @ORM\Column(name="oldData", type="blob", nullable=false)
 * 
 * @Serializer\Expose 
 */
private $oldData;

/**
 * Set oldData
 * 
 * @param $Data
 */
public function setOldData( $data )
{
    $this->oldData = serialize( $data );

    return $this;
}
```

I'm using this class in another controller:

```
$log = new ChangeLog();
$log->setUser( $this->getUser() );
$log->setOfferBase( $ConditionSet->getOfferbaseId() );
$log->setOldData( $ConditionSet );
```

After i saved the new object im using following code to save the new changes in the log:

```
$log->setNewData( $ConditionSet );

$em->persist( $log );
$em->flush();
```

The problem is that the datas aren't saved in the database and i got a 0 byte blob. I doesn't get any error but in my log I saw that symfony didn't tried to save the data:

```
doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO changeLog (changeDate, offerBase, user) VALUES (?, ?, ?) {"1":"2016-08-09 17:28:39","2":45,"3":1} []
```

I tried the following to catch the exception. But output is "No exception".

```
try { 
    $em->persist( $log );
    $em->flush();
    $message = "No exception";
} catch (DBALException $e) {
    $message = sprintf('DBALException [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $message = sprintf('PDOException [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
} catch (ORMException $e) {
    $message = sprintf('ORMException [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message = sprintf('Exception [%i]: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
}
return new Response($message);
```